# jquery how to get a value and place it elsewhere?

Tags: jquery

I would like to get the value `<span>Expertise discovery</span>` and add a title to the href like so:  `<a href="discovery.html" title="Expertise discovery">`

```
<li class="tooltip-parent">
    <a href="discovery.html">
    <span>
        <img src="discovery.png"/>
    </span>
    </a>
    <div class="tooltip">
        <span>Expertise discovery</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like

```
$('.tooltip-parent').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.children('a').attr('title', $this.find('.tooltip span').text())
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gzx4V/)

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this :

```
//find the span inside tooltip and get its contents
var title = $(".tooltip").find("span").text();  
//select the a tag with href set to discovery.html and add the title attribute to it.
$('[href="discovery.html"]').attr("title", title);
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vDNCS/)

This will do the changes you need, to this and all other images with the same markup structure.

```
$('.tooltip').each(function(){
    var val = $(this).text(); 
    $(this).parent().find('a').prop('title',val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[href='discovery.html']").attr("title", $(".tooltip > span").text());
```

OR

```
$(".tooltip-parent > a").attr("title", $(".tooltip > span").text());
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
$('a[href="discovery.html"]').attr("title",$(".tooltip-parent .tooltip").find('span').text(););
```